# Issue PHP + Apache server on OS X Sierra

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm absolutely new to PHP and trying to solve one task. Here's my code:

```
<a href="task92.php?category=sport">Sport news</a> | <a href="task92.php?category=politics">Politic news</a><br/><br/>
<a href="task92.php?category=sport&format=json">Sport news (JSON)</a> | <a href="task92.php?category=politics&format=json">Politic news (JSON)</a><br/><br/>

<?php
$news = ["sport"=>["C. Ronaldo has scored three goals in last five matches","Golovkin has won match for title"],"politics"=>["Trump has cancelled his visit to North Corea, because of sanction","N. Nazarbayev has approved new version of alphabet"]];
$category = null;
$format = null

if(isset($_GET['category'])){
    $category = $_GET['category'];
    foreach ($news[$category] as $value) {
        echo <p>$value</p>;     
    }
} 
elseif(isset($_GET['category'] && $_GET['format'])){
    $category = $_GET['category'];
    echo json_encode($news[$category]);
}
```

When I'm clicking on a link it gives me "Not Found
The requested URL /task92.php was not found on this server." I've tried to rewrite my https.conf, and enabled AllowOverride, but still doesn't work for me. I would be very grateful to any help!

Comment: have you checked if they are the same files? they're also case-sensitive too.

Comment: what files have to be the same?

Comment: i mean is this script named **task92.php**? it appears you're just linking to itself so it should work.